# Spark Dataframe converting into RDD with map function

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark

I am trying to split the column in a spark data frame into values. So I separated the column I wanted to split and checked its type:

```
I: type(TopicModelVectorSplit)
O: pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame
```

When I split the string using:

```
TopicModelVectorSplit = TopicModelVector.select('TopicModelVector').map(lambda line: line.text.split())
```

It converts to a pipilined RDD and those are impossible to work with.

```
I: type(TopicModelVectorSplit)
O: pyspark.rdd.PipelinedRDD
```

How can I split this column and still keep the data frame property intact?

Thanks a million

Comment: Have you tried to use `pyspark.sql.functions.split`?

Answer (score 0):

You can always convert it back to a dataframe using .toDF, but RDD are not impossible to work with, you might as well fine what you want keeping it as such.

```
Split = TopicModelVector.select('TopicModelVector').map(lambda line: line.text.split()).toDF
```